# Is there any way for a Consumer to send an acknowledgement to a producer implemented using kafka(kafka.js) and node.js?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, producer-consumer, kafkajs

I believe the 3 types of acknowledgement as the producer properties are limited to the leader and the producer, I want the producer to receive a concrete message when the consumer consumes a message from the storage/queue through kafka broker.
Also correct me if I am wrong on the '*acks*' property of the producer, it's default is '-1' which acknowledges whether all the replicas have received/stored the message, but does it have anything to do with the consumer, or can we create a bridge when the consumer commits and kafka sends acknowledgement to producer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consumer and Producer are isolated components and there is no out of the box acknowledgement framework between the two in the Kafka API; you'd have to implement this on your own

Your understanding of the acks is correct, but has no control over consumer behavior, which always reads from the leader partition when message becomes available

Comment: Yeah I know this, I was wondering whether there's any logic that I am missing, or whether can we do something with commits and acknowledgements to build a bridge. One such implementation is to send a acknowledgement message from consumer to a different topic in kafka cluster from which the producer will consume. But is this really possible as how can we keep track of producers, if the rate of message consumption is less that rate of message production?

Comment: There's nothing in the nodejs Kafka libraries that provide that, so you're not missing anything. Producers don't consume. And consumers don't produce messages back outside of the offset commit. You'd have to build that process on your own, as stated. I don't understand your question about the rate; consumer threads just idle for new messages when they reach the end of a partition

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you.